# How do I overwrite my old files in EC2 with the new ones I upload from S3?

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I updated my old website files and zipped them into a folder before sending it to s3 for storage. When I downloaded the files into my ec2 and unzipped them and moved them into var/www/html rather than replacing the old files (which were the exact same name) they simply changed the name into index(1).html and page2(1).html.

Is there a way I can quickly replace my old files with the new ones?

Comment: How did you download and move those files? Just using e.g. `s3 sync` or `mv` will not create suffixes like that.

Comment: I use wget and copy paste the link from s3 and then I use the mv command after unzipping my folder

Comment: Please edit your question to show the commands you used. Also, show the directory before and after unzipping the zip file. Those filenames suggest that an operating system was trying to avoid overwriting files. Are you using Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

unzip the files within the /var/www/html and use -o flag to overwrite files.